# Using crypto library from wallet

Tags: source

I'm trying to access functions from the crypto libray such as:
`ge_frombytes_vartime(ge_p3 *h, const unsigned char *s)`
`ge_p3_to_p2(ge_p2 *r, const ge_p3 *p)`
both in crypto-ops.c

I've added the crypto lib to the CMakeList:

```
target_link_libraries(wallet
  PUBLIC
    multisig
    common
    cryptonote_core
    mnemonics
    cncrypto <-- This one
    ${LMDB_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY}
  PRIVATE
    ${EXTRA_LIBRARIES})
```

and I get the following error from the linker:

```
 98%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/monero-wallet-cli
../wallet/libwallet.so: undefined reference to `ge_frombytes_vartime(ge_p3*, unsigned char const*)'
../wallet/libwallet.so: undefined reference to `ge_p3_to_p2(ge_p2*, ge_p3 const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/simplewallet/CMakeFiles/simplewallet.dir/build.make:122: recipe for target 'bin/monero-wallet-cli' failed
make[3]: *** [bin/monero-wallet-cli] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2688: recipe for target 'src/simplewallet/CMakeFiles/simplewallet.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [src/simplewallet/CMakeFiles/simplewallet.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2700: recipe for target 'src/simplewallet/CMakeFiles/simplewallet.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [src/simplewallet/CMakeFiles/simplewallet.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:812: recipe for target 'simplewallet' failed
make: *** [simplewallet] Error 2
```

I can't figure out where the problem is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably linking them in as C++.
Lookup the different in linkage between C and C++, and/or copy how Monero already does, ie:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "c_header.h"
}
```

Alternatively, rctOps.h has a convenience layer above these if performance isn't critical.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between C and C++ linkage? or send me a link

Comment: I added an example.